# no jQuery on inserted HTML

Tags: jquery

I have jQuery loaded in the head of my page, to do something on click of elements with a certain class.

```
$(function(){
  $(".addtocal").click(function(){
  $(this).next('.addToCalOptions').fadeIn('fast');
  return false;
  }
);
});
```

It works for all the .addtocal elements already present on the page. But not with a bunch of similar elements inserted in the page later by a jQuery .load function.

Now I'm pretty sure I have to use a "a delegated-events approachth" with the .on() function. Right?

This doesn't work, though:

```
$(function(){
  $("a").on("click", ".addtocal", function(){
  $(this).next('.addToCalOptions').fadeIn('fast');
  }
);
});
```

I'm lost. Any thoughts? Thanks!

Comment: http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delgation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use document as delegate, because delegate have to be static (not dynamically added):

```
$(function(){
  $(document).on("click", ".addtocal", function(){
  $(this).next('.addToCalOptions').fadeIn('fast');
  }
);
```

But better is to use closest static container instead of document.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(function(){
    $(document).on("click", ".addtocal", function(){
        $(this).next('.addToCalOptions').fadeIn('fast');
    }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

try this first with `document`, if this does work, probably `a` is not the container for 
`.addtocal` which already exists in DOM. You can then scale down `document` to a container that already exists in DOM.

```
$(function(){
  $(document).on("click", ".addtocal", function(){
  $(this).next('.addToCalOptions').fadeIn('fast');
  }
);
```

and if you identify the container you can write it as:-

```
 $(function(){
      $("containerSelector").on("click", ".addtocal", function(){
      $(this).next('.addToCalOptions').fadeIn('fast');
      }
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use jQuery `on` syntax correctly. and for the `on` API, you dont need to add ready event since it is only fire once you clicked the items

```
$(document).on("click", ".addtocal", function(){
    $(this).next('.addToCalOptions').fadeIn('fast');
}
```